# MySQL group by like statement?

Tags: mysql, group-by, like

I need to get some stats out of our MySQL-DB and wonder if there is a faster way in doing this.

Basically I need info about user registration for any given month before including seperation by attributes.

e.G:

```
SELECT count(*) AS c  
FROM `users` 
WHERE `date_created` LIKE '2015-10%' 
  AND `country` = 'DE'
```

This would return a number for October 2015. How could I alter this statement to return results for all months within one statement?

I would also be interested in adding something like `AND confirmed = 1` as separate result.

Is this possible with just one MySQL-Statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_created) AS yr,   -- for each year
   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_created) AS mth, -- & month combination 
   count(*) AS c,                                 -- count all rows 
   SUM(CASE WHEN confirmed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -- count only confirmed rows 
FROM users
WHERE country = 'DE'
GROUP BY yr, mth
```

Comment: The OP is asking to speed it up; this won't help; it will still scan all dates.

Answer (score 6):

Two things are needed to make it run faster:

**Get suitable index**

Without `confirmed = 1`, you need

```
INDEX(country, date_created)
```

With it, you need

```
INDEX(country, confirmed, date_created)
```

**Avoid hiding the date in a function**

`LIKE '2015-10%'` cannot use an index on `date_created`, nor can `MONTH(date_created)`, so let's reformulate the query:

```
WHERE date_created >= '2015-10-01'
  AND date_created  < '2015-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND confirmed = 1   -- add this if you want to limit to confirmed rows
```

(This assumes that `date_created` is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype.)

**All Months**

This query can still use the two indexes I suggest, however, it won't necessarily use the `date_created` part.

```
SELECT LEFT(date_created, 7) AS YYYY_MM,
       COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM tbl
    WHERE country = 'DE'
      AND confirmed = 1   -- if you want this
    GROUP BY YYYY_MM;
```

**Note about `country_code`**

A common mistake in defining the schema (please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) is to define it as `CHAR(2)` and default to utf8.  This leads to using 6 bytes, when 2 would suffice.  Change to `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`.